# Fixed thead in jQuery Mobile table

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, html-table

I have tried to solve this problem for a few hours now. There a lot of plugins for fixed theads, but non of them seem to work with jQuery Mobile.

for example:
http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/

I also tried to solve this with CSS, and this works more or less. But the width of `th` columns is not the same as the `td`'s.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
<h1>test</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<table data-role="table" id="table-custom-2" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive" data-column-btn-theme="b" data-column-btn-text="Columns to display..." data-column-popup-theme="a">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-bar-d">
        <th data-priority="2">Rank</th>
        <th>Movie Title</th>
        <th data-priority="3">Year</th>
        <th data-priority="1"><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Rating</abbr></th>
        <th data-priority="5">Reviews</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td>
        <td>1941</td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td>74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_(film)" data-rel="external">Casablanca</a></td>
        <td>1942</td>
        <td>97%</td>
        <td>64</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather" data-rel="external">The Godfather</a></td>
        <td>1972</td>
        <td>97%</td>
        <td>87</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gone_with_the_Wind_(film)" data-rel="external">Gone with the Wind</a></td>
        <td>1939</td>
        <td>96%</td>
        <td>87</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>5</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_of_Arabia_(film)" data-rel="external">Lawrence of Arabia</a></td>
        <td>1962</td>
        <td>94%</td>
        <td>87</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>6</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove" data-rel="external">Dr. Strangelove Or How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb</a></td>
        <td>1964</td>
        <td>92%</td>
        <td>74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>7</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Graduate" data-rel="external">The Graduate</a></td>
        <td>1967</td>
        <td>91%</td>
        <td>122</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>8</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)" data-rel="external">The Wizard of Oz</a></td>
        <td>1939</td>
        <td>90%</td>
        <td>72</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>9</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singin%27_in_the_Rain" data-rel="external">Singin' in the Rain</a></td>
        <td>1952</td>
        <td>89%</td>
        <td>85</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>8</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)" data-rel="external">The Wizard of Oz</a></td>
        <td>1939</td>
        <td>90%</td>
        <td>72</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>9</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singin%27_in_the_Rain" data-rel="external">Singin' in the Rain</a></td>
        <td>1952</td>
        <td>89%</td>
        <td>85</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>8</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)" data-rel="external">The Wizard of Oz</a></td>
        <td>1939</td>
        <td>90%</td>
        <td>72</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>9</th>
        <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singin%27_in_the_Rain" data-rel="external">Singin' in the Rain</a></td>
        <td>1952</td>
        <td>89%</td>
        <td>85</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>78</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
<h1>test</h1>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
thead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 44px;
    left: 15px;
    background-color: white;
}
table {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.ui-table-columntoggle-btn {
    display: none !important;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StefanCerdijn/uNj3g/)

There are much more, but I don't have enough rep to post more.

Does anyone have any experience with jQM and fixed theads?

Comment: What jQuery have you used to try and do what you're wanting to do? You link to a jsfiddle and you've tagged the post with two jQuery related tags, but I see absolutely no jQuery.

Comment: i am the author of floatThead - I am curious as to why you think it does not work with jquery mobile? I think it does, but you just need to understand the nuances of how jquery mobile loads pages and what that means for how you init plugins

Comment: @mkoryak i tried your plugin with my jQueryMobile app, plugin created a div outsite of my table container. position given to that div was absolute. when i scroll my page my thead doesn't get fixed. when i see in your page div's top is updated dynamically..but for my page it doesn't. I have initialized plugin with below code..              $("#tableItems").floatThead({
                scrollContainer: function ($table) {
                    return $table.closest('#tableContainer');
                }
            });

Comment: please use github to report issues. they can turn into a long back and forth, and stackoverflow is not a suitable place for that.

Answer (score 1):

As [mkoryak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26188/mkoryak) stated in his reply, floatThead works with jQuery Mobile.  I just ran in to the same need for my website.  I used jQuery 2.1.1 and jQM 1.4.4.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">...</div>
            <!-- /header -->

            <div id="contentContainer" class="ui-content">
                <div id="tableContainer">
                    <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive table-stroke table-stripe" id="tableItems">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>COL 1</th>
                                <th>COL 2</th>
                                <th>COL 3</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>FIELD 1A</td>
                                <td>FIELD 2A</td>
                                <td>FIELD 3A</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>FIELD 1B</td>
                                <td>FIELD 2B</td>
                                <td>FIELD 3B</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>FIELD 1C</td>
                                <td>FIELD 2C</td>
                                <td>FIELD 3C</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">...</div>
            <!-- /footer -->
        </div>
        ...
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tableItems").floatThead({
                scrollContainer: function ($table) {
                    return $table.closest('#contentContainer');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested but no luck ..it does n't work !! what happens is my thead flows on the page header and then goes up..can you please suggest if any thing extra has to be done in the configuration..